# jquery date time picker current time

Tags: jquery

I want to fill the datetime picker with the current system time.  Used the below way.  Time is in 24 hour format but it's less by  1 hour desktop time.  Checked the timezone it's not having issues. 
Pasted the jquery code below

```
$('#srch_id_schd_time').datetimepicker({
        controlType: 'select',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
});
$('#srch_id_schd_time').datetimepicker('setDate',(new Date()));
```

Pasted the html code below

```
<!-- Scheduled Run Time -->
<input id="srch_id_schd_time" type="text" name="srch_id_schd_time" />
```

Comment: ur about to show only time or both date/time...

Comment: Showing both date and time.  Default time is showing 1 hr less than the desktop time.